# Apache 2 Vhost listen issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I am adding a VHost (two, actually, on 80 and 443) to an existing config that does the same thing for two other names to Apache/2.2.9 / Debian.

The symptom is that Apache happily starts with no errors, the other two are fine, but the new one throws connection refused for both ports. I have verified DNS and firewall settings.

Apache is happily Listening correctly (Listen directives: Listen *:80 Listen: *:443)

```
www:/etc/apache2# lsof -n -i
apache2 8983 www-data    7u  IPv6  39301       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
apache2 8984 www-data    5u  IPv6  39297       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
```

I verified the network config for the IP address, and it accepts connections for, e.g. ssh.

The Vhost is (names/IP changed)

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:443>
    Servername www.site.com
```

I checked for overlap with other server configs, there isn't any. I compared the config with the other VHosts that are working, and the only differences are names and IPs.

And idea what I could be missing?

Comment: `netstat -na`, pls. I can't see IPv4 open ports, but VHost is (?) IPv4

Answer (score 1):

Is there an interface on your host set to listen to 10.0.0.2?  If not,

```
ifconfig -a|grep 10.0.0.2
```

will yield no output.

Comment: Looks like he said he faked the IP he listed, but its a valid exercise.